# Markdown multiline link support

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm currently trying to add a multiline text with several links and it seems that the link stops working on line break, any suggestions on how to fix this?
Thanks!

```
 Text("I agree with [Privacy Policy](https://url.com) and [Terms of service](https://url.com/tos)")
```

I tried adding fixed line breaks with `\n`, but that didn't have any effect.
I've also tried adding `try! AttributedString(markdown: )` but that as well didn't achieve my desired goal.

Comment: The '\n' in between works fine here (Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4), where did you inserted it?

Comment: right before "and" so it looked like `(https://url.com) \n and ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try multi-line strings.

```swift
Text("""
     I agree with [Privacy Policy](https://url.com)
    and [Terms of service](https://url.com/tos)
""")
```

[image: example-1]

```swift
HStack{
    Text("""
    Spausdami registruotis sutinkate su mūsų [Privatumo Politika](https://darbomanija.lt/privacy)
    ir [Naudojimosi Taisyklėmis](https://darbomanija.lt/tos)
    """)
}
```

[image: example-2]

Comment: Unfortunately no luck

Comment: @n3xt0 it’s working fine on my end. You don’t need to \n. Just put the text on a new line.

Comment: so my code currently looks like this: 
`HStack{
Text("""
Spausdami registruotis sutinkate su mūsų [Privatumo Politika](https://darbomanija.lt/privacy) ir [Naudojimosi Taisyklėmis](https://darbomanija.lt/tos)
""")
.font(Font.custom("MazzardM-Regular", size: 16))
.foregroundColor(Color(xelaColor: .Gray5))
.frame(height: 50, alignment: .leading)
.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
Spacer()
}`

Comment: You're setting the height of the frame, it's getting cut off. I updated the answer.

Comment: It appears that after removing all the styling attributes it indeed works, but for example when a keyboard in in view, the hstack becomes single line with ... in the back. How can i add some styling to the font and the hstack itself without breaking the markdown?